# Discord Bot: Wrong number from BigInt

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm saving the user id (with my bot) of my members at the Discord Server on my MYSQL. Now let's say i saved a id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX as a Big Int. The saving works perfectly fine, i looked in the database and it's the same. Now if i want to get this number it's changing to: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX00.

Code:

```
con2.query(`SELECT * FROM discord_user WHERE discord_id = '${id}'`, (err, result, fields) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            var string=JSON.stringify(result);
            var json =  JSON.parse(string);

            message.author.send(json[0].discord_id);
```

Does anyone know what issue that could be?

Comment: WARNING: Your code is vulnerable to a sql-injection attack. Read more about it [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Also read [here](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md) to find out how to fix it

Comment: Save it as a string instead and see if that doesn't solve the problem. If the problem persists, it has something to do with how you add the value to your SQL. If it works as intended then it is in fact a problem with big int.

Comment: Thank you kemicofa, i will try.

Comment: Solved by using string, thank you so much stuck on this for hours!